# how do i combine these associations in class diagram

Tags: uml, software-design

[image]

Below is a uml diagram, which describes relationship between a company at a particular location and its employees( full time and part time) and consultants.  Constraints are an employee cannot be a consultant.A person can be a full time and a part time in another.

Comment: I mean the associations between employee and consultant.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a dashed line with "{OR}" title? You don't need it all.

According to your diagram, Employee cannot be Consultant simply by the nature that they are both inherited *directly* from Person. Employee and Consultant have the same super class but they cannot substitute each other. Once again, it's the nature of inheritance, you don't need "{OR}" line.

Comment: No i am asking what i mean i have two relationships called full time employee and part time employee. I want to keep the two relationships into one. Also is a company can be at multiple locations is the locations qualifier correct?

Comment: You can collapse "part time employee" and "full time employee" into a single "employee" relationship, but then you would need to introduce this concept on Employee class level. This could be done using sub-classing which is most likely an overkill, or by using an attribute: type, status, isFullTime, etc. Company-Location-Person relationship seems to be fine.

Comment: Just wanted to stress that's it's perfectly fine to have two distinct relationships like "part time employees" and "full time employees" between two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a single association class WorksIn and add as attriubte of the association class a boolean attribute "PartTime" to state if the employee works in that company location part time or full time